# SSH and execute any command returns "logname: no login name"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to SSH from one Unix host to another and execute some commands. 
Whenever I run  `ssh hostname <any command>` I get back "logname: no login name".
I can succesfully just `ssh hostname` and then execute the same command without any issues. SSH is setup to use rsa keys for password-less connections.
Everything works fine using a different user account so I suspect it might be related to bash profile or something along those lines? I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: There is something in the `.bashrc`/other environment scripts that is trying to process the output of the `logname` command. Generally sections that are running in non-interactive scripts should be guarded from execution.

Comment: If it's generating the same error on every command, then please check the ~/.bashrc on remote host. 'logname' command must be there in that file.

Comment: turns out there was that in the .bashrc "PS1="\u(\033[1;33m$(logname)\033[1;0m)@$HOSTNAME:$SHLVL:\w \n$ ". One more mystery to solve: ssh connection is active after the command executed - is there a way to terminate it after grabbing output?

Comment: Did you change anything in ~/.bashrc? Which command did you execute?

Comment: Removed reference to logname in PS1. It behaves same no matter what you run i.e. ssh host "cat foo.txt". Problem I have now that cat is not giving any output and ssh is not being closed - after ssh host "cat foo.txt" terminal is still on the remote host.